# Create Individual User Accounts retroactively asp.net core 2

Tags: authentication, asp.net-core

I have created a web application using .net core 2.  When I set it up I chose no authentication.  Now I would like to add individual user authentication.  Is this possible once the application has been setup?  Maybe a command in the pm console?

I can make another project and select authentication.  Is there a list of files that I can copy over to my existing web site?

Comment: Just make a new project with authentication and add the stuff in `Startup.cs` specific to Identity. Follow the trail of missing dependencies to copy over what you need (`ApplicationUser`, `ApplicationDbContext`, etc). Then, it's just the `AccountController` and `ManageController`, which you can take as a whole or piecemeal.

Answer (score 1):

It is a little late but maybe it will help other people:

[Microsoft Documentation Security](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/scaffold-identity?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=visual-studio)

---

It covers scaffolding Identity in ASP.NET Core projects. More precisely:

- Scaffold identity into an empty project
- Scaffold identity into a Razor project without existing authorization
- Scaffold identity into a Razor project with authorization
- Scaffold identity into an MVC project without existing authorization
- Scaffold identity into an MVC project without existing authorization
- Scaffold identity into an MVC project with authorization
- Create full identity UI source

Greegtings Luki

Comment: Whilst this link may answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts (not the ToC) of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Well I didnt know which project style is used but thank you for your input I will try to improve my answers in the future.